# Updating video source on graph click in Dash Python

Tags: python, html, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have a html.video element in my app layout, along with a graph, when I click on an element of the graph I want to update the video element, to a video corresponding that section of the dataset.

The below is how I have my app layout set up.

```
app.layout = html.Div([

    html.H1("Belfast Harbor Data Overview", style ={'text-align': 'center'}),

    #Droptown for machine type

    dcc.Dropdown(id="slct_machine",
                 options=[{'label': k, 'value': k} for k in all_options.keys()],
                 multi=False,
                 value=options1[0],
                 style={'width': "70%"}

                 ),

    #Dropdown for date
    dcc.Dropdown(id="selct_date",
                 style={'width': "70%"},
    ),

    #HTML Break
    html.Br(),
   
    dcc.Graph(id='hist', figure={}, style={'width': "90%"},
        config={
            'staticPlot': False,  # True, False
            'scrollZoom': True,  # True, False
            'doubleClick': 'reset',  # 'reset', 'autosize' or 'reset+autosize', False
            'showTips': False,  # True, False
            'displayModeBar': True,  # True, False, 'hover'
            'watermark': True,
                  # 'modeBarButtonsToRemove': ['pan2d','select2d'],
              },),


    html.Video(
        controls=True,
        id='video_player',
        src={},
        autoPlay=False,
        style={'width': "70%"}
    ),
```

After this, I have some callback functions for my graph and a function to populate the graph with data.

Following this, I have another app call back and here I am trying to update the video player with some test data. I have done this as follows:

```
@app.callback (
    Output('video_player', 'src'),
    [Input('hist', 'clickData')]
)

def updateVideo(clk_data, src):
    if clk_data is None:
        video_src = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"
    else:
        print(f'hover data: {clk_data}')
        video_src = "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm"
    return video_src
```

I get the following callback error when I do this:

[image: Error received]

I am not really sure why the src is not updating, as passing components seems to work like this for figures and containers.

There are other elements to the app as well but I feel they aren't consequential as the video source is the part that is not updating.

I can provide all the code if required, but I feel I am simply updating the video source incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of arguments in your function definition (currently two) must match the number of inputs (+ number of states) to your callback (currently one). Hence your should remove the (unused) src argument, or add another input or state.

Comment: Of course! Thanks, as always far more simple than I thought it was!